# How to add data to Model being on View (Full Model goes to Controller)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am really new to ASP.NET MVC, and I need your help guys.
I have this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<fieldset>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <br />
    <p>Answer: </p>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, 6, 80, null);
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send Answer" />
</fieldset>
}
```

It's a partial View, that has a form, and the Model data inputed goes to Controller by a input:submit, standard MVC.

But when the user hits the submit, I want to send some info that it's not user inputed, and it's in the model and the view, like, thread_id, user_id, so I can form the model to send to Controller to populate the database.

```
    public int idAnswer { get; set; }
    public int idThread{ get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int idProfile{ get; set; }
    public System.DateTime dtAnswer{ get; set; }

    public virtual tb_Profile tb_Profile { get; set; }
    public virtual tb_Thread tb_Thread { get; set; }
```

This is my model, yeah, it's autogenerated by Entity, so even if I have the idThread, idProfile, I got the tb_Profile and tb_Thread to fill.

How can I do it?

Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1):

If the input is in the model, add it in the view, inside the model, as hidden fields:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.thread_id)
```

The user won't see it, and won't be able to manipualte it, but it will be posted with the rest of the form.